# basis for intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose
>   $$\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$$
>   and 
>   $$\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_m\}$$
>   are bases for an $n$- and $m$-dimensional space respectively.
>
> Form the matrix
>   $$M= 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   v_1 & v_2 & \ldots & v_n & w_1 & w_2 & \ldots & w_m 
> \end{bmatrix} =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   V & W
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   and find basis for its nullspace. Let the basis be 
>   $$\{u_1,\ldots,u_p\}$$
>   where each $u_i=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   a_i \\
>   b_i
> \end{bmatrix}
> $.
>   Then $\{Va_i, \dots, Va_p\}$ is a basis for the intersection subspace.

Could anyone tell me what does he mean by each $u_i=...?$ what is $a_i$ and $b_i$?. well Suppose I found a basis for null space of $[V \hspace{0.2cm}W]$ and suppose it is a matrix $P$ (means its columns are basis for null space), could anyone tell me is he saying that $VP$ will give me the basis for the intersection of subspaces generated by columns of matrices $V$ and $W$? I assume that $v_i$ and $w_i$ are column vector.
Thank you for help and solution.
http://www.ece.iit.edu/pipermail/ece531/2002-March/000025.html

Comment: I have attempted to retype the text from your picture. Perhaps you can check whether it says something along the lines what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked about meaning of $u_i$, $a_i$, $b_i$. This seems to be a reasonable interpretation:

I will assume that you use *column* vectors.

If you have a vector from a nullspace of $M$, this means that
$$Mu=0.$$
In particular, the vector $u$ has $n+m$ coordinates, we can divide it into the vector $a$ which contains the first $n$ coordinates and $b$ which contain the rest.
So you have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  V & W
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  a \\
  b 
\end{bmatrix}=0,
$$
i.e.,
$$Va+Wb=0.$$

In particular, this means that
$$Va=-Wb.$$
The vector from the last equation is a linear combination of columns of $V$ and at the same time it is a linear combination of columns of $W$. Which means that it belongs to the intersection of the two subspaces.